# check on json response (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, correlation, gatling

I want to do a sanity-check on the response I get from a request and verify that element1 is 2017 in the below response:

```
body=
{
  "id"        : { "element1": "2017", "element2": "ST", "nivaa": "land", "navn": "element3", "nr": "0" },
```

How do I do that in something like this format:

```
.check(jsonPath("$._element").is("2017")))
```

The code above does not work.

What do I put in where it says `"$._element"`

Comment: Please, clarify which one JSON library do you use? Based on the JSON library you can get an answer on your question

Comment: I use json+hal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using this in Gatling project, I may assume you work with [JSONpath](https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath). According to its documentation, if you want to get a value of `element1` field from the body, you have to use following construction:

```
$.id.element1
```

or its equivalent:

```
$[id][element1]
```

Please, let me know about your result